# How to quantify pixel changes in a short video

Tags: matlab, video, pixel

I have been using short (20s) videos as stimulus material in a recent study. I would now like to compare the videos regarding the amount of movements that each video contains.

This is my code until now:

```
VidObj = VideoReader(video_file); 
VidFrames = read(VidObj);
```

returns 4D Matrix = 2d array of 2d images = a x b x c x VidNoFrames

```
VidNoFrames = VidObj.NumberofFrames; 
VidHeight = VidObj.Height; 
VidWidth = VidObj.Width; 

    for k = 1 : VidNoFrames 
       k mov(k).cdata = VidFrames(:,:,:,k); %720 x 1280 x 3 
    end
```

Now I guess the next step would constructing the loop for correlation/SSD. However, cdata is still 3D (height x width x 3). I do not understand what this third dimension is and how to go on comparing the images... Thanks so much for your help!

Thanks a lot!
Christine

Comment: Show the code you have so far. It is not clear what is blocking you. Do you know for example how to load a video and access its frame data?

Comment: I am at the very beginning of investigating that question and mainly meant to collect some ideas on how to do it. 
No, I do not yet know how to load a video and access its frame data...:(

Comment: A question asking for lists of ideas is not a great fit for Stack Overflow (because there is not a correct answer). Consider making a start, and coming back when you have a practical coding question, with a more specific technical goal. It is ok to ask multiple simple questions, and often better for the site than one big "help me with my project" question

Comment: @Christine this question is quite different from your previous one in which you asked about ways to compare images. I suggest creating another question with this specific bit of code. And if the answer helps you please accept it so the thread is closed thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use correlation to compare 2 images, or in your case I would opt for computing the Sum Square Intensity Difference, which tells you in a more quantitative way maybe how much pixel intensity differs from one image to another. Here is a simple example for both cases;

```
clear
clc

%// Correlation coefficient. Close to 1 == more similarity
A = imread('coins.png');

B = medfilt2(A);

CorrCoeff = corr2(A,B)

%// Sum Square Intensity Difference


SquareIntDiff = (B-A).^2; %//Compute the square of the pixel intensity difference.

SSID = sum(SquareIntDiff(:)) %// Sum it to get the SSID. A value of 0 means that both images are similar in terms of pixel intensity. 
%// Using sum(sum(SquareIntDiff)) would yield the same result in a less efficient manner. MATLAB  takes the sum along the columns and then another time to get a single value.


CorrCoeff =

    0.9964


SSID =

      550746
```

Of course you can easily implement this in a loop to compare consecutive frames in your video. Hope that helps you a bit :)

Comment: Do you need `bsxfun` there?

Comment: Oops actually no; I had a similar code I use for processing image sequences so bsxfun was necessary but in this case it's not you're right!

Comment: SSD is what is usually implemented for most MPEG standards for video.  Good job!

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng! Good to know an expert on the matter agrees with the idea ;)

Comment: And I continue to bother - You can use this `sum(SquareIntDiff(:))` for more performance.

Comment: @Divakar yep I wrote it as a comment; I thought it would be easier for the OP to understand the process using sum twice. I'll make it as the first choice though

Comment: @Benoit_11 Damn, sorry my bad, didn't see that one !:) +1 for you already

Comment: @Divakar sure no problem! I actually inverted the methods since it makes more sense to propose the most efficient solution first :)